# Sharp MX-4101N MFP for 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, network-printer

I am having absolutely no luck getting the Sharp MX-4101N network printer drivers to work on 64-bit operating systems (Windows 7 and Windows 8). I had already installed some Windows 7 32-bit workstations a couple of years ago and they continue to work just fine. I had also saved the 64-bit drivers on hand for future installs.

However, neither those older drivers, nor the [brand spanking new drivers from Sharp](http://www.sharpusa.com/CustomerSupport/ProductDownloads.aspx) are working. I tried every possible download available from Sharp for this printer, the PCL6 driver, the universal driver, the WHQL driver, on both the Windows 7 and Windows 8 machines. In all cases, the driver installs fine and the printer is visible in the control panel. The universal driver also requires some additional config to connect to the specific printer model, which I also did (this is detailed in the accompanying PDF installation instructions).

But when I try to print, the MX-4101N's fan kicks up to high gear as if it received the data and is getting ready to print, and then... nothing. No error in Windows, no error on the printer screen, nada. Every printer driver reinstall was preceded by a complete uninstall of the previous drivers, so I'm at a loss as to what to do next. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Generally the Postscript driver works best for this particular MFP product.  But if you can't get any drivers to work, you can actually use HP drivers with it.  I found that if you want full functionality from this printer, though, you need .NET 4.0 as well as the mfr's drivers.

One other thing I found with these is that when you install the new driver, the old one remains.  In Windows 7, open the Devices & Printers folder. Click once to highliight one of the installed printers.  Up at the top, you should now see "Print Server Properties"; click on that. Click on the Drivers tab there, and remove all the Sharp drivers.  Restart your system and install the Sharp postscript driver from scratch.

[image: List of installed printer drivers]

The drivers are here, though I usually get them from the printer tech:

[http://www.sharp-idncservice.com/DesktopModules/SharpDriver/SDdlViewFile.aspx?IDFile=13325&file=MX_C28_PCL6_PS_1105a_EnglishUS_XPVistax64.zip&location=\10.0.10.65](http://www.sharp-idncservice.com/DesktopModules/SharpDriver/SDdlViewFile.aspx?IDFile=13325&file=MX_C28_PCL6_PS_1105a_EnglishUS_XPVistax64.zip&location=%5C10.0.10.65)\index\idncservice\DriverFiles\MX_C28_PCL6_PS_1105a_EnglishUS_XPVistax64.zip&From=SharpUSA
(64-bit WHQL PCL6/PS driver)

[http://www.sharp-idncservice.com/DesktopModules/SharpDriver/SDdlViewFile.aspx?IDFile=13257&file=MX_C28_PCL6_PS_1212a_EnglishUS_64bit.zip&location=\10.0.10.65](http://www.sharp-idncservice.com/DesktopModules/SharpDriver/SDdlViewFile.aspx?IDFile=13257&file=MX_C28_PCL6_PS_1212a_EnglishUS_64bit.zip&location=%5C10.0.10.65)\index\idncservice\DriverFiles\MX_C28_PCL6_PS_1212a_EnglishUS_64bit.zip&From=SharpUSA
(64-bit mfr PCL6/PS driver)
etc. from

http://www.sharpusa.com/CustomerSupport/ProductDownloads.aspx?model=MX-4101N

How are you setting up the port?  Does the printer's admin log show your job arriving at all?

Answer (score 0):

The MX-4101N may require the PostScript option to be installed.  It will dump any print jobs sent to it without the MX-PKX1 PostScript Kit installed (a 'key' to enable the functionality).
The symptom you described is consistent with trying to use a PostScript driver on a non-equipped Sharp MFP.

Comment: Do you mean the postscript option to be installed on the printer? Like I said, the drivers on 32-bit Windows work fine, it's just the new 64-bit installs that aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

Without the PostScript (PS) option installed, the printer will behave as you've described.  If your Windows 32-bit POSTSCRIPT driver worked, then most likely the PS option is installed on the MX-4101N already.